# Identify cell that don't contain "formula"

Tags: excel

version: Excel 2010

Is there a way to quickly identify or create a simple marco to identify cells that doesn't have a formula?

```
--------------------------------
|=A1*1 |   151 | =A3*1 | =A4*1 |
--------------------------------
|=B1*1 | =B2*1 |   100 | =B4*1 | 
--------------------------------
```

quickly highlight or change font colour of cell with 151, and 100?

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be [This answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/753293/excel-2010-highlight-cells-used-in-any-formula/1053460#1053460) will be useful to you, it classifies the selected cells into "input", "output" and "calculation" categories and assigns the respective cell style. I find it easy to understand or debug sheet. For your scenario you should be looking for cells without any styles and cells with "input" style while using this macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do it without VBA is to select the range you want test, press Ctrl+G and then click`Special`.

Then specify the type of cells you want and click OK and only those types of cells will remain selected.  In your case, select `Constants` to select all cells without formulas.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In 2010 and earlier, you need a custom VBA UDF for that. Along the lines of

```
Function IsFormula(cell_ref As Range)
    IsFormula = cell_ref.HasFormula
End Function
```

Then use it like

=ISFORMULA(A1)

In Excel 2013 and later there is a built-in function ISFORMULA() that does the same thing natively.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use conditional formatting to highlight cells that not contain a formula.

1. Open Name-Manager (CTRL+F3)
2. Create a new name, e.g. "noformula", enter

   ```
   =NOT(GET.CELL(48,INDIRECT("RC",FALSE)))
   ```
3. Create a custom formatting rule for the desired area. Use

   ```
   =noformula
   ```

   as selection rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting to highlight cells that aren't formulas.  This is great for formula driven tables that occasionally need manual input.  The manual inputs highlight automatically if they are not formulas.

In conditional formatting highlight a cell then (use formula to determine which cell to format):
`=ISFORMULA(A1)=FALSE`

Then format paint cell A1 around to expand the conditional format.